# why hovering li elements change their position onmouseover and onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to highlight one li element on mouse hover and at the same time hide other li elemnts. Script works fine. But on mouse hover the element "something" starts to change it's position, so he gets out of mouse cursor triggering onmouseout script, which changes it's position to default again. This causes crazy loop. How to hide a, b, and etc. elements without changing the position of first element?

Here is html code:

```
<li><a href="#" id ="something" onmousemove="changeCSSIn()" onmouseout = "changeCSSOut()" >something</a></li>
<li> id ="a"...</li>
<li> id ="b"...</li>
<li> id ="c"...</li>
```

And this is script:

```
function changeCSSIn (){


    var something;
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;



    something = document.getElementById('something');
    a = document.getElementById('a');
    c = document.getElementById('b');
    d = document.getElementById('c');


    something.style.color = "red";
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
```

}

function changeCSSOut() {

```
    var something;
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;



    something = document.getElementById('something');
    a = document.getElementById('a');
    c = document.getElementById('b');
    d = document.getElementById('c');


    something.style.color = "#DBDBDB";
    a.style.display = "initial";
    b.style.display = "initial";
    c.style.display = "initial";
```

}

Comment: We'd need to see it. Can you make a JSFiddle? Try opacity changes insteas of `display:none` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Might be because id="something" is on the <a> tag and not on the <li>.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, opacity is the thing i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'visibility: hidden' instead of 'display: none'. This way the elements won't be rendered, but they are still there.